# HTML <style> use in bash script

Tags: html, css, bash, stylesheet

I am trying to remove the bullets in some HTML code created with a bash script.  Currently, I seem to be having difficulty applying the style to the whole program.  I have little to no experience with html and believe i may be misunderstanding or misplacing .  Any help would be appreciated. The code is for a  file hierarchy for a passed in directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1" || exit 1

cat<<EOF
<html>
<body>
<style>
ul.tree, ul.tree ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
</style>
EOF

NESTDEPTH=0

find ./* | while read F; do
    SLASHES=$(echo "$F" | tr -c -d '/' | wc -m | tr -d ' ');

if [ $SLASHES -gt $NESTDEPTH ];then
    VAR=$(($SLASHES - $NESTDEPTH))
    while [ $VAR -gt 0 ]; do
        printf "<ul> \n"
        VAR=$(($VAR - 1))
done
elif [ $NESTDEPTH -gt $SLASHES ]; then
    VAR=$(($NESTDEPTH - $SLASHES))
    while [ $VAR -gt 0 ];do
        printf "</ul> \n"
        VAR=$(($VAR - 1))
done
    else
    exit 1
fi

NESTDEPTH=$SLASHES 
FNAME=$(basename "$F")
echo "<li>$FNAME"

while [ $NESTDEPTH -ne 0 ];do
    echo "</ul>"
    NESTDEPTH=$(($NESTDEPTH - 1))
done

done


cat<<EOF
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Comment: I think better to use python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the no-bullet style only applies to lists marked with the class "tree" but it doesn't look as though "tree" is ever applied to any of the `<ul>`s. Try changing the CSS selector from `ul.tree, ul.tree ul` to just `ul`.